# Install Insta360 Studio with Wine

Tags: wine

I've heard that it is possible to install Insta360 studio

[Insta360 Studio](https://www.insta360.com/support/supportcourse?post_id=20328)

with wine on Ubuntu. I have been unable to get it to work by just using play on linux with defaults. If anybody knows step by step how to do this would be great!

Comment: Have you checked out the Wine Site to see what they say about running and using that app on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for installing Insta360 Studio (2023_Winx64_4.7.6 build_202305151846) on Ubuntu 23.04 using Bottles. All functions work fine.

1. Install [bottles](https://usebottles.com).
2. Create new bottle. In settings select runner sys-wine-8.0.
3. Install Insta360 Studio.

---

Instructions for installing Insta360 Studio (2023_Winx64_4.7.6 build_202305151846) on Ubuntu 23.04 using portproton. All functions work.

1. Install portproton_1.0-2_amd64 from https://github.com/Castro-Fidel/PortProton_dpkg/releases.
2. Click right botton on file "Insta360 Studio 2023_Winx64_4.7.6_build_202305151846.exe" select "open with" then "PortProton".
3. Run PortProton. Select from the bottom menu "Installed" then "Create shortcut.." and select "Insta360 Studio 2023". [Now you can run Insta360 Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4hMr.png).
4. After starting the program, you will be prompted to select additional settings. [In the EDIT DB menu, disable NO_ESYNC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfV8G.png). Download and use runner wine 8.5.
5. If you're using a 4K monitor, you'll probably want Insta360 Studio to scale as well. To do this open PortProton select "Wine Settings" then "WineCfg" and under "Graphics" set it to 192 dpi.
6. If you are using Nvidia Prime then switch to Performance mode. Unfortunately, when using Nvidia on-demand, you will not be able to run Insta360 Studio on a discrete graphics card. In this case, an openGL error will appear.

Comment: Is this also a good place to ask about using the Insta360 Link webcam on Ubuntu? any luck anyone?